# Delete a vBulletin user account automatically using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

I want to cleanup my vBulletin users automatically by a script that filters them on certain condition and e.g. delete spam registration accounts after some amount of time. This could be easily done in the MySQL database using

```
DELETE FROM user where userid = 123;
```

and in PHP with the VB core included

```
$vbulletin->db->query_write('DELETE FROM user where userid = ' . $userId);
```

but on my test installation I see some side effects. For example, the user is still listed in the community members. Seems that VB caches data that doesn't get purged when directly deleting on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Fist require `global.php` from the vBulletin root to have core functions like `fetch_userinfo` avaliable as well as a working database connection:

```
require_once './global.php';
```

(modify this to the corresponding paths on your environment if required) and load the userinfo of the affected user:

```
$info = fetch_userinfo($userId);
```

Now we can modify and also delete an user by creating an instance of the user datamanager:

```
$userdm = datamanager_init('User', $vbulletin, ERRTYPE_CP);
$userdm->set_existing($info);
$userdm->delete();
```

In scripts without VBs protection mechanism, it make sense to validate the user before. For example, we could check if it's an undeleteable user from the config before deleting like this:

```
if (is_unalterable_user($userId)){
    print_stop_message('user_is_protected_from_alteration_by_undeletableusers_var');
}
```